# Unable to insertBefore each DOMNodeList item in php. Only last item is updated

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to add tag `<input type="checkbox">` before every li that has class `menu-item-has-children` but the dom is updating only for the last item not all. The code is written below:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $sanitized_menu );
    $finder = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $inner_menus = $finder->query( "/html/body//li[ contains( @class, 'menu-item-has-children' ) ]");

    // element to be added
    $elem = $dom->createElement('input');
    $elem_attr = $dom->createAttribute( 'type' );
    $elem_attr->value = 'checkbox';
    $elem->appendChild( $elem_attr );

    $index = 0;

    while( $index < $inner_menus->length ) {
        $insert_val = $inner_menus->item( $index );
        $insert_val->parentNode->insertBefore( $elem, $insert_val);
        $index++;
    }

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    print_r( $html );
```

Answer (score 1):

You only create one input and then you append it multiple times.

Since an element can't exist in multiple places at once, that **moves** it.

Create the element **inside** the `while` loop.

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked, can't upvote, sorry low reputation

Comment: Another option would be to clone the node inside the loop: `$insert_val->parentNode->insertBefore( $elem->cloneNode(TRUE), $insert_val);`